# I'm trying to get Ubuntu alongside with Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

When I get to the boot loader, I select Ubuntu. It gives errors like *software or hardware has recently been changed and to insert windows install disc*. Any ideas on how to fix? I'm new to this, I want to try Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you give us an actual example of the error in code?

Comment: Do you get this error when selecting Ubuntu? It seems strange it would give you a message about Windows...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually mean is that you **cannot boot Windows** when you select it in Grub menu as it happens often when Windows partition is changed from outside, e.g. Ubuntu.

And the solution for this problem is: using **Windows Recovery Disk** to repair Windows boot manager. If you haven't created already you can even download a small **iso** file from the internet and either write it to a CD or even a USB stick using **MultiSystem** live USB creator utility which you can install under Ubuntu.

Comment: when i select windows it loads up just fine, but when i choose to load up Ubuntu, it give me that info.

Comment: please give the exact message you see when you're trying to boot ubuntu so that you can receive a good answer; with so little information nobody can help... you can perhaps try using ubuntu live cd/dvd/usb, install and use boot repair utility - see: https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/boot-repair